# How to display AES encryption key in laravel using Encrypter package?

Tags: laravel, encryption, aes

I want to allow the user to generate custom keys to encrypt their message before sending it. The user will need to see the generated key first but when I pass it to the blade, it doesn't get displayed because it's not a string I guess. I Couldn't find a way to display it.

```
    public function index(){

    $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';

    $key = Encrypter::generateKey($cipher);

    return view('dashboard.compose',compact('key'));
}
```

Comment: [generateKey](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.html#method_generateKey) does return a string. How are you displaying it in your view?

Comment: I can't display it, that's the thing. I've been trying to display it. If you pass it, it doesn't show in the view.

Comment: Try outputting with `{{ bin2hex($key) }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!